# After updating npm to 3.8 python related error occurs when npm build

Tags: python, npm

At first, the npm build worked fine and I've been using it ever since. I saw the update information during today's build, and ad error occurs after the update.

I have an answer that reinstalls python2.7

```
sudo apt install python2
```

and worked.
So should npm build be tied to 2.7?
Is there any way to build using python3 together?
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for reading.

```
npm install -g npm // update

npm --version
>> 8.12.1

whereis python
>> python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.8

npm config set python "usr/bin/python3"    

sudo npm run build

> worlture-content-process@1.0.0 build
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.19.3 | linux | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-113-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/worlture/node_s/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/worlture/node_s
gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: You should be updating your version of `node-gyp`. `node-gyp` landed support for [Python 3 in 2019](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/v5.0.1/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: npm install -g node-gyp@latest
npm config set python "/usr/bin/python3.8" Now, It's worked. Thanks muru.